# how to set json with comment in vscode?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I often use Vs code to open json files. sometimes there're some comments in my json files. in this case,there will be a lot of warnings.

So I click below button to change the format to "json with comment (jsonc)"

[image]
[image]

but when I open a JSON file next time, it will by default switch to JSON format (without comment)

How can I make 'jsonc' the default format of json file? so that I do not need to change it every time.

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can set a file association between `json` files and `jsonc` language formatting.

In VS Code open Settings in JSON view by using the Command Pallet (`Cmd` + `Shift` + `P`) and enter `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`. Next, add the following (or append to the existing `files.associations` object if it already exists):

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.json": "jsonc"
}
```

Comment: you're right.  but i am so  afraid to change setting file directly . i may broken it and cannot recover it.

Comment: And   F1 =  Cmd + Shift + P